# Only close JavaFX application

Tags: java, javafx, lwjgl

I am trying to make a `LWJGL` game run a `JavaFX` application and the game, then close only the `JavaFX` application, but doing `System.exit(0)` closes both windows.

How can I get the desired result

Comment: What about [`Stage.close`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#close--)?

Comment: As @M.leRutte mentions, closing the last `Stage` will cause the JavaFX runtime to exit (so long as `Platform.isImplicitExit() == true`). You could also call [`Platform.exit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#exit()) explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a common close function where You just need to pass [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html). Node can be Button, ComboBox, TextField etc.

```
public static Stage closeConfirmView(Node node) throws IOException {        
        Stage primaryStage = (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
        primaryStage.close();
        return primaryStage;        
}
```

Comment: what is the benefit of  returning the closed stage ?

Comment: If user want to perform some action on that stage like getting controller of that stage or somethings else. It's not necessary although, without it function will work fine.